# Second pass over written previous list contents

Tags: c#

I have the following function which works fine and produces the results when their is one table selected. But when there is two tables being selected my _newList function is just replacing the fields in the array I will show you in graphical form best i can.

```
private void genXmlSchema_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<TableDefnition> _newList = new List<TableDefnition>();
        PersistentObject _testObjects = new PersistentObject();
        List<GridViewRowInfo> _checkRows = GetCheckedRows(rgTableNames);
        List<PersistentObject> _testObjectsList = new List<PersistentObject>();
        foreach (GridViewRowInfo row in _checkRows)
        {


            var currentRow = (TableNames)row.DataBoundItem;

            _newList = db.GetALLTableDeiniations(currentRow.TABLE_NAME);
            rgFieldsOfTable.DataSource = db.GetALLTableDeiniations(currentRow.TABLE_NAME);
            _testObjectsList.Add( BuildSchema(_newList, currentRow.TABLE_NAME));

        }
        _newPObject.PersistentObjects.AddRange(_testObjectsList);

        _newPObject.ClassPrefix = "Persistent";
        _newPObject.ClassSuffix = "";
        _newPObject.Language = "VB";
        _newPObject.Path = @"C:\Sage200SchemaExtensions";
        _newPObject.GenerateSeparateFiles = "false";
        _newPObject.GenerateBusinessObjects = "false";
        _newPObject.BaselineSchema = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Sage 200 SDK\SageObjectStore.xml";
        _newPObject.DataTypes = "";
        _newPObject.Enumerations = "";
        _newPObject.MemberVariablePrefix = "_";
        _newPObject.ApplicationNamespace = "BusinessObjects";
        schemeContent.Text = HelperXml.ToXML(_newPObject);
    }
```

[image]
On the second pass you will that it has duplicated the second table in both of the lists.

First Array Number after second pass

[image]

Second Array Number after second pass
[image]

As you can clearly see its lost the reference to the first table with 4 columns completely I no its something simple to do with my list creation and destruction but cant figure it out

Comment: Hi, think you forgot to add values/pic in the question.

Comment: @peeyushsingh values are showing in the debug information